# unique_ptr vs shared_ptr - design

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, c++14, c++17

I'm writing a card game. I have the following classes: Card, Deck, Player, Board, GameLogic.

Deck holds a vector of unique_ptr Cards. Then a card is drawn from the deck and passed to a player. Then player picks a card and puts... Here I have a design problem. Because up to now it's totally fine to have a unique_ptr. But then I want to pass a card to both Board and GameLogic.

Currently I converted a unique_ptr to shared_ptr. But I find it either ugly and not logical.

I believe that proper usage of pointers is very important and should tell you about the lifetime of a variable. I'm doing something wrong but don't know what...

Do you have some suggestion about how to solve it?

Comment: My usual recommendation is not to see the smart pointers as just some simple self-deleting pointer, but in terms of *ownership*. Will a "resource" have multiple owners (`std::shared_ptr`) or just one owner (`std::unique_ptr`)? Perhaps smart pointers aren't correct here, but you should use plain *non-owning* pointers? Or think up a design where you *don't need* pointers?

Comment: Why do you use pointers and not just card values?

Comment: Why do you have `unique_ptr<Card>`s? Is Card polymorphic (and why)? You could just have a `vector<Card>` and copy them around by value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Nothing wrong with one owner having a shared pointer, and then non-owners getting weak pointers to it.  Sure you could be writing in Java for the syntax you end up with, but it'll work perfectly well.

Comment: @UKMonkey You have to have a specific reason to need weak pointers because they're slow. But when they're needed, they are great!

Comment: @Galik Very good in multithreading observer pattern, where you can't figure out when an observer is gone.

Comment: So does your game logic need the card for more than a function?  (i.e. does your logic engine need to own the card at all?)  If not, why not just pass it a raw pointer while the player owns the card with its unique ptr?  If that's the case, perhaps passing the card by reference is a cleaner solution?

Comment: Without further information, if you **must** use pointers (and I don't see why you would) then it seems to me the cards need only **one** owner (at a time) that will last the duration of the game (because you never duplicate cards). That would suggest a `std::unique_ptr` and you can pass the *raw pointers* to the various game logic functions.

Comment: Regarding using a pointer: I have different type of cards. Only some of them can be put on a board. That's why I use pointers/polymorphism. And about using a copy. I thought that using a unique pointer I can guarantee that a card won't "cloned", used twice etc.

Answer (score 2):

To use objects with specific life spans:

- Prefer values over pointers.  Copy the values or pass references as needed, but don't store the references as the referenced value can be removed.
- When pointers are needed, prefer `unique_pointer` if you can identify one owner. Pass references as needed, but don't store them.
- Use `shared_pointer` when there are multiple owners or when "references" need to be stored. Pass `weak_pointers`, which can be stored and locked as needed.

Remark that you could also give some id as reference so later on, you could access objects that could have been removed.  If your `Card` is nothing more than an id (queen of hearts), just pass a copy of it.

Comment: No, my card is more than that. There are many different types of cards. Some of them can be put on the board, some can be used to fight, some to block, some to free... etc. There are many parameters that describe every type of card. So I don't think I would be a good idea to put them all into one class. Do you?

Answer (score 1):

Following your own words:

> Deck holds a vector of unique_ptr Cards. Then a card is drawn from the
>   deck and passed to a player. Then player picks a card and puts... Here
>   I have a design problem. Because up to now it's totally fine to have a
>   unique_ptr. But then I want to pass a card to both Board and
>   GameLogic.

Probably you create each card in the constructor. Though it is perfectly feasible, I don't see the point. Provided there are always the same, fixed, number of cards. I mean, you don't create new cards of each type or whatever.

I would just create the deck of cards as a simple array, and pass average pointers to players and so on. The cards will be just destroyed when the deck is destroyed.

```
class Deck {
public:
    const static int NumCards = ...;
...
private:
    Card cards[NumCards];
};

class Player {
public:
    void dealt(Card*[] cards);
};
```

One of the advantages of C++ is that lets you choose between storing objects in the heap or the stack. While the former is more flexible (when the number of available cards changes over time, for example), the latter is much more efficient, provided you know the number of items beforehand, as apparently you do in this case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As you can see my other comments I need polimorphizm. But besides that what I do not like in such a solution is that I need some other variable to manage drawing cards from deck. When I have pointers I can get a card from a deck.

Comment: I suppose you need polymorphism because you have one class for each type of card. That can be done differently, simplifying to just one Card class, but anyway. About "another variable", yes, you need another collection in order to store in Player which cards have been dealt. However, that's much better than moving cards from one place to another one.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the sentiment in the other answers that pointers aren't strictly necessary here, the simplest way to go if you *do* use pointers is to employ references:

```
class Deck
{
private:
    std::vector<unique_ptr<Card>> cards;
public:
    const Card& get_card(unsigned index); // returns cards[index]
}
```

A `const` reference allows you to reference it without having to convert it to `shared_ptr` (and without the risk of other parts of the code modifying it).

Comment: OK. I got your solution. I just thought that taking a card from a deck is a good idea. Like mimic the real world where if you draw a card then it's no longer in the deck. And I hoped it would help me to avoid mistakes. When you copy a value then you have to remember to remove it from all the places.

Comment: Aah, if that's what you want you can do so! `std::move` the `unique_ptr` from the `Deck` to the `Player`, then it's obviously owned by the player and no longer in the deck. After that you can pass it by reference to `Board` (using the solution above)!

Comment: OK. But then a player can put a card (he does not hold it no longer). So maybe then I should `std::move` it to some managing object and pass a raw pointer to both `Logic` and `Board`. What do you think?

Comment: Well, it sounds like any card is always part of either the `Deck`, a `Player`, or the `Board`. So it would make sense to keep a `unique_ptr` in one of those classes, and pass a reference to the `Logic` (or have the `Logic` read out the other classes, depends on the implementation).

Comment: Aside from that, you could also use raw pointers rather than references – the main difference here is that a reference can't be `null`, which sounds like what you want here.

Answer (score -1):

if you are not satisfied with both shared pointer and unique pointer, there is no better option than normal pointer. Use observer pattern which is helpful when one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically.